# How to add dependency and build java code using buck

Tags: java, buck

Can anyone please help me to build my code? I downloaded jedis (redis client) using maven but when I am trying to build my code using buck, it's giving an error that the  Jedis package cannot be found.

Attaching my buck file here:

```
prebuilt_jar(
  name = "jedis",
  maven_coords = "redis.clients.jedis:jar:3.0.2",
  binary_jar = "jedis-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  visibility = [
    "PUBLIC",
  ],
)
```

What exactly should be my buck file to add redis jar?

Comment: Is it listed in dependencies for java library/binary, i.e. `deps = [':jedis']`?

Comment: its not added there..also i couldnt find this folder to add dependency.could you please guide me more. @kolen